# Add 15 minutes to current time and snap to 15 minute intervals

Tags: php, datetime

I need to add 15 minutes to the current time.
For eg : now is  `20:48` , need to add 15 minutes, so now it will be `21:03`, but i need to set 21:15 ,that is , it should be in multiples of`15,30,45,00`.
Help help/guidance would be of good help.

```
<?php
$current_date_time = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$current_date = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($current_date_time."+15 minutes"));
echo $current_date;exit;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: 20:48 -> 21:03 -> 21:15 ?

Comment: @deceze: have you read the title??!! ;-P (a reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022361/need-to-add-15-mintues-to-current-time#comment24601935_17022450)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simple example

```
//what time is it?
$t=time();

//how long is our interval?
$interval=15*60;

//we can calculate when the last interval started by subtracting $t % $interval
$last = $t - $t % $interval;

//so now we know when the next interval will start...
$next = $last + $interval;

echo "Next interval at ".strftime('%H:%M:%S', $next)."\n";
```

You look like you might want to add 2*$interval to the last interval, but you should be able to adapt this to suit you.

Comment: What a fantastic solution!

Comment: I saw the rash of bad answers and had to jump in :)

Comment: Given the utc leap second (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) and because you are using utc time() function. Will this really round nicely to the nearest 15 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

Just to correct my post:

```
    $time = time();
    $last_time = ($time - ($time % (15 * 60)));
    $in15mins =  $last_time+ (15 * 60);
    echo 'Now:        '. date('Y-m-d H:i') ."\n";
    echo 'in 15 mins: '. date('Y-m-d H:i', $in15mins) ."\n";
```

I think it is quite self explaining. Optimize it, use it.

Comment: this is flawed, consider what happens if the two calls to time() return different results.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_date_time = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
echo $current_date_time."<br>";
$current_date = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($current_date_time."+15 minutes"));
echo $current_date."<br>";
$minutes = date("i",strtotime($current_date));
$min = '';
if($minutes > 0 && $minutes <15){
    $min = 15 - $minutes;
} else if($minutes > 15 && $minutes <30){
       $min = 30 - $minutes;
} else if($minutes > 30 && $minutes <45){
       $min = 45 - $minutes;
} else {
       $min = 59 - $minutes;
       $min++;
}

$newdate = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($current_date."+".$min." minutes"));

echo $newdate;
```

Use the above code. this is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
$currentTimeStamp=strtotime('now');
$nextInterval=date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+15 minutes", $currentTimeStamp));
dump($nextInterval);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)